# Dialogflow v2 NodeJS API ContextsClient

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Pretty simple one here, I'm looking for documentation for the various clients offered by the Dialogflow v2 nodejs library.

Following their implementations on Github I see various uses of 
 "`new dialogflow.ContextsClient();`" (and other clients) but can't seem to find documentation for what I can do with that `ContextsClient`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [the RPC reference here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/) and the [samples in the Github repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2)

Here is an example of how you can create a context with the ContextsClient: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/blob/master/samples/resource.js#L902

Comment: the RPC reference was what I was looking for, thanks!